# Jmeter, In 'View Results in Table', what does 'Bytes' indicate?

Tags: apache, report, byte, jmeter

Jmeter, In 'View Results in Table', what does 'Bytes' indicate? 
Is it the number of bytes recieved from the Server?

The Report contains:
Sample#,
StartTime,
LAbel,
SampleTime(ms),
Status,
Bytes [ What does this indicate??]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Bytes represents the quantity of data in the sample response returned from the server.